# R: install package using putty

Tags: windows, r, putty

After I run my R script on windows, I would like to use another server machine for the calculations. I use putty and the cloud computing provider slicify.

Thats what I did until now:

```
sudo tsocks apt-get install r-base-core #R
sudo tsocks apt-get install default-jre #java
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
tsocks wget #to upload my R script
tsocks wget #to upload data which are used by the R script
```

so far so good. I then run R and get into the R envieronment.

In R i try to install some packages like:

```
install.packages("nloptr", repors="")
```

Thats what follows:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/slicify/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
```

I then choose a server in switzerland and continue. It takes a lot of time and finally I get this error:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/src/contrib
Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") :
  unable to connect to 'cran.r-project.org' on port 80.
2: In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘nloptr’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)
```

Can someone help me with above issue? thank you very much

UPDATE:

error on (the command line does not go on)

```
install.packages("nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",repos = NULL, type="source")

Installing package(s) into ‘/home/slicify/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: cannot extract package from ‘nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz’
Warning message:
In install.packages("nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages("nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz",repos = NULL, type="source")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/slicify/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘nloptr’ ...
** package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: Now testing for NLopt header file.
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking nlopt.h usability... no
checking nlopt.h presence... no
checking for nlopt.h... no
configure: Need to download and build NLopt
trying URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
Error in download.file(url = "http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",  :
  cannot open URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url = "http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",  :
  unable to connect to 'ab-initio.mit.edu' on port 80.
Execution halted
/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Warning message:
In untar(tarfile = "nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz") :
  '/bin/tar -xf 'nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'' returned error code 2
configure: Starting to install library to /tmp/Rtmpch92Ql/R.INSTALL31457068e238/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2
./configure: line 3325: cd: nlopt-2.4.2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where are you in the world?  Which is the closest mirror to you?

Comment: For the second warning suggests to compile an R package from source. 1- download the source zip, 2- `install.packages("/path/to/file/nloptr.tgz",repos = NULL, type="source")`. For the first warning check if you have some firewall/or other service blocking the port 80.

Comment: you probably have to ask the slicify support team for help ... `nloptr` should be available as a binary, as http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/nloptr_0.8.9.zip exists.

Comment: you *might* be able to `sudo apt-get install r-cran-nloptr` ...

Comment: @RichardScriven I am in switzerland and choosed that one from switzerland

Comment: @agstudy thanks, but i get an error message on this: > install.packages("nloptr_1.0.4.zip",repos = NULL, type="source")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/slicify/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) :
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\.....

Comment: @BenBolker I will contact the admin. your suggestion did not work for me. thanks all

Comment: @Valegard234 : to install a `.zip` file you should *not* use `type="source"`;  use `type="source"` if and only if you have `nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz`

Comment: @BenBolker thanks the error looks much better now. Since it is a lot I put it into my question.

Comment: `nloptr` is unusual among R packages in requiring an additional download. https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/215 discusses this in passing (although mostly about other issues).  It *might* be possible to do the download separately and work around that issue that way: see https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr/blob/master/configure or contact the package maintainer ... ??